# Laravel 10 Fortify twoFactorAuthentication options

Tags: php, laravel, fortify, two-factor-authentication, laravel-fortify

After publishing Foritfy I see the following options for the twoFactorAuthentication feature

```
Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
    'confirm' => true,
    'confirmPassword' => true,
    'window' => 0,
]),
```

Fortify documentation mentions that password confirmation which I assume is the confirmPassword option. I couldn't find anything regarding the other options:

```
'confirm' =>,
'window' => 0,
```

Can someone please tell me what do these options do or point me to where I can find more information about it.

- It also makes me wonder if there are other options

Tried finding relevant information in the offical laravel documentation but no luck